# How to recode to allow targeting single status?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code that looks for certain woocommerce subscription statuses. I'm trying show a different message for each of the following statuses 'canceled' and 'paused'. Would you know how I can adapt this block of code to achieve that?

```
<?php
function can_user_access_content($user_id,$post_id){

    //check if there's a force public on this content    
    if(get_post_meta($post_id,'_wc_memberships_force_public',true) == 'yes') 
        return true;
    $args = array( 'status' => array( 'active','complimentary'));


    $plans = wc_memberships_get_user_memberships( $user_id, $args );
    $user_plans = array();
    if (is_array($plans)) {
        foreach ($plans as $plan) {
            array_push($user_plans,$plan->plan_id);
        }
    }
    $rules = wc_memberships()->get_rules_instance()->get_post_content_restriction_rules( $post_id );

    foreach ($rules as $rule) {
        if(in_array($rule->get_membership_plan_id(), $user_plans)){
            return true;
        }
    }       
    return false;
}

if (can_user_access_content(get_current_user_id(),$post->ID)) {
    echo ('has active subscription'); 
} 
?>
```

So I'm trying to see if I can have something similar to this following after the above block of code...

```
<?php if 'status' = 'paused' { ?>
<?php echo ('Your account has been paused ...'); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I don't exactly know what your code does but try to return your status (preferred as an int) instead of true/false. Define to yourself what status is false (usually something like -1). Then you can check what the status is using this return value.